# Travelling to Greece via Cairo, do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, egypt

Me and my fiance are travelling to Greece for honeymoon. I got our tickets booked on EgyptAir from Mumbai to Athens with layover in Cairo. We don't intend to go out of the Cairo airport as the layover period is only 4 hours long on both onward and return journey. Do we need to apply for Egypt visa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=EG&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Transit without Visa: Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit
>     time of 48 hours.

So no, you do **not** need a visa

Comment: The OP didn't state his nationality. Your Timatic search says `Not applicable to nationals of Iran who must hold a transit visa`, and has some limitations for other countries.

Comment: @ugoren Pretty sure they're Indian judging by their Point of departure and Profile pic

Comment: @Coke How come my profile pic is judged Indian ? :-)

Comment: @Bennie You changed it since July

Comment: No, I'm using 'Bennie and the Jets' since the start.